# Why can't I create this table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE AverageStudents 
AS 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM StudentData 
      WHERE GPA > 3.0);
```

I keep getting the error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Does my simple code look alright to you?
I really want a table (not a view, thanks for suggestion though).

Comment: I'd suggest you look up create table in BOoks online. This is not even close to correct code. Also look up the select into clause.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This erroneous syntax is a mix of creating table, creating view and selecting...

Comment: What would you like to do exactly ? both bhamby and devart answers here under could be an answer depending on the question...

Comment: phan - MySQL and Oracle both support `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`, but SQL Server doesn't. In SQL Server it's `SELECT ... INTO`, as pointed out by @devart and others.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo check out this webpage, it's where I got the idea from.  I want to create a new table from another table (and use all of the columns for rows where GPA > 3.0)  http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php

Comment: It won't work on mssql.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo That's where my confusion lies.  I thought SQL was universal...I didn't realize there was the MSSQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
INTO AverageStudents 
FROM StudentData 
WHERE GPA > 3.0
```

Or this -

```
CREATE VIEW AverageStudents 
AS
     SELECT *
     FROM StudentData 
     WHERE GPA > 3.0
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for [a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

```
CREATE VIEW AverageStudents AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM StudentData 
  WHERE GPA > 3.0;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really do want a table then try the code below:

```
  SELECT * 
  INTO AverageStudents
  FROM StudentData 
  WHERE GPA > 3.0
```

Howver, it sounds like a view would probably be more appropriate as suggested by bhamby

Answer (score 3):

I think bhamby's right but if you really want a table

```
SELECT * 
INTO AverageStudents
FROM StudentData
WHERE GPA > 3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for [SELECT INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)